# pasar array de php a array json y luego a array javascripit

Tags: javascript, php, json

tengo un array en php,  este lo estoy usando  buscar categorias y paises etc pero lo e echo todo en php y me dicen queesas cosas mejor las haga en javascript para que camine mas rapido, no se que me recomiendan ustedes, el echo es que ahora quiero pasar este array de php al javascript para ejecutar las consultas y todo desde alli pero cuando paso mi array de php a json con **json_encode**    y luego desde javascript lo trato de convertir en un array de javascript con **JSON.parse**  me arroja un error, y creo que mi array de php no esta bien echo para pasarlo asi o no se que pasa, me gustaria que me ayudaran en esto.... y adicional ps todo lo tenia echo en php, vale la pena hacer este tipo de cosas en javascript? me mejora el rendimiento? por que la pagina la siento muy pegada, aqui les dejo el codigo.

array php

```
        $data_consult_venezuela[] = [
            
            "idpais" => $idpais,
            "iddepartamento" => $iddepartamento,
            "idprovincia" => $idprovincia,
            "idmunicipios" => $idmunicipios,
            "idzona_urb" => $idzona_urb,
            "idtipo_comercio" => $idtipo_comercio,
            "idcategoria" => $idcategoria,
            "idsubcategoria" => $idsubcategoria,
            "idsubcategoria_final" => $idsubcategoria_final,
            "idultima_categoria" => $idultima_categoria,
            "pais" => utf8_decode($pais),
            "departamento" => utf8_decode($departamento),
            "municipios" => utf8_decode($municipios),
            "provincias" => utf8_decode($provincias),
            "zona_urb" => utf8_decode($zona_urb),
            "categoria" => utf8_decode($categoria),
            "subcategoria" => utf8_decode($subcategoria),
            "subcategoria_final" => utf8_decode($subcategoria_final),
            "categoria" => utf8_decode($ultima_categoria),
            "comercio" => utf8_decode($tipo_comercio)

            
    ];
```

luego coloco el script para pasarlo a json

```
<script>
var data_consult_venezuela = <?php echo json_encode($data_consult_venezuela); ?>;

</script>
```

luego coloco el Json .parsen para pasarlo a array javascript y empezar a hacer los recorridos y me da el error.

```
    var as = JSON.parse(data_consult_venezuela);
```

el error es el siguiente, como si no esta bien echo  el array de json.

VM79779:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON
at JSON.parse ()

Comment: El rendimiento depende de lo que quieras hacer con los objetos del `array`. Hay una diferencia entre `Javascript` que se ejecuta en el computador del cliente y `PHP` que se ejecuta en el servidor. Desde `PHP` por ejemplo, podrías iterar el `array` y maquetar `HTML` antes de devolverlo a la vista, pero si necesitas ejecutar una acción por cada objeto desde la vista, si es mucho mejor iterar el `array` desde `JS` y así no tienes que hacer una petición al servidor en cada iteración.

Comment: Otro aspecto a tener en cuenta son los recursos de hardware que tiene el servidor (_procesador, memoria, etc. Si son pocos, va a tardar más tiempo en responder_) y la ubicación del mismo, ya que a mayor distancia, mayor latencia (_el tiempo que tarda un paquete en trasportarse a través de la red_).

Comment: si es que en este caso lo que estoy haciendo es para el cambio de categorías, por ejemplo si la categoría es productos  y la cambias ps que aparezca todo lo relacionado a alimentos y así sucesivamente, lo estaba haciendo con con recorridos de array en php y todo me daba bien pero la cuestion es que como es un market me da miedo que si llega mucha fluencia de usuarios se quede pegado, por eso pense una de las opciones con JS a ver si ejecutanto esos datos en la maquina del usuario seria mas rápido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios errores:

1. Repites la clave categoria, la claves deben ser unicas
2. Ya es un objeto

```
var data_consult_venezuela = <?php echo json_encode($data_consult_venezuela); ?>;
```

Esta linea es un array con un solo objeto dentro. Y lo que pasa es que un JSON cuando no está como string puede pasar como objeto. Para decirlo de otra manera, esto cuando se renderiza, el servidor envía lo siguiente al navegador

```
var data_consult_venezuela = [{"idpais" : 23 ...etc }];
```

Que es tal cual como se escribe un objeto (array)

3. Si tú lo que quieres es poner un json debes envolverlo entre comilla simple

```
var data_consult_venezuela = '<?php echo json_encode($data_consult_venezuela); ?>';
var as = JSON.parse(data_consult_venezuela);
```

Comment: efectivamente con esto que me dices resolví este problema, pero me encuentro en una encrucijada, para mostrar  los campos de categorias, sub categorias o paises, departamento, provincias, es mejor realizarlo des JS o PHP? actualmente tenia todo en php pero los datos  de los paises, departamentos y municipios lo tenia todo guardados en array y a medida que seleccionan cada select  estos iban cambiando, pero este tipo de cosas caminan mejor en JS? en cuanto a velicidad, como es un market me da miedo  que en algún momento colapse  o sea muyyyy lento.

Comment: @proyectosglobalesdeventilac En lo personal, los guardo en js. Finalmente el sitio anda mejor si no tiene que ir a buscar a cada rato información al servidor, que es lo impacta mayormente al performance (sobre todo si no ocupas ajax, porque tiene que renderizar todo nuevamente). Y en mi experiencia un par de miles de datos guardados en el navegador no afecta el rendimiento. Lo sí afecta el rendimiento son plugin de terceros para generar páginas como Elementor de wordpress

Comment: @proyectosglobalesdeventilac Si la respuesta ha resuelto el problema, recuerda dejarla como aceptada. Saludos

Comment: si ya resolvi el problema muchas gracias, donde la marco como aceptada? estoy buscando a ver, y ya voy a publicar otro detallito con el que ando, y si efectivamente estoy pasando estoy JS no queda de otra a pesar que mi pagina esta solo con JS PHP y AJAX